# '$set' is empty even though it's not

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a problem in updating a document in MongoDB... 
in the params.sendingMethodPushTime and SmsTime i receive a new Date();

tried setting the $ set inside the update function itself and tried to use hardcoded values

```
userScheme.statics.updateAlertSendingTimes = function (params, cb) {
    var query = {uId: params.uIds};
    var set = {};
    if (params.alertType) {
        set['alertSendingTimes'] = {};
        set['alertSendingTimes'][params.alertType] = {};
        set['alertSendingTimes'][params.alertType]['push'] = params.sendingMethodPushTime;
        set['alertSendingTimes'][params.alertType]['sms'] = params.sendingMethodSmsTime;
        var update = {
            '$set': set
        }
        this.update(query, update, {upsert: true}, cb);
    } else {
        cb(null)
    }
};
```

$set should pass and MongoDB document is updated but instead, I get $set is empty etc

EDIT: my mongoose version is 4.13.4 and my node version is 6.16 and params.alertType is a string received dynamically (in my case it's '​1' or '2')

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the scheme... it was alerts and not alert